# ValueError: not enough values to unpack Split function

Tags: python, split, python-3.6

Iam trying to code this

```
highest_score = 0
result_f = open('results.txt')
for line in result_f:
    (name, score) = line.split()
    if float(score) > highest_score:
        highest_score = float(score)
result_f.close()
print("the Highest score was: ")
print(highest_score)
```

Contents of `results.txt`:

```
Johnny  8.65 
Juan  9.12 
Joseph  8.45 
Stacey  7.81 
Aideen  8.05 
Zack  7.21
Aaron  8.31
```

Iam Actually reading Head first to python Book
And I Got This Code Example But It is'nt Working For me 
i Dont Know What My Mistake Is Can Someone Please Figure This Out Iam Using Python3.6

Comment: What does `results.txt` contain?

Comment: Can you include an example line from `results.txt`?

Comment: this : Johnny  8.65 
Juan  9.12 
Joseph  8.45 
Stacey  7.81 
Aideen  8.05 
Zack  7.21
Aaron  8.31

Comment: for a better example check here                                      http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfprog/chapter04/results.txt

Comment: Empty line at the end?

Comment: Your code works fine for me with the file you linked here. Are you sure you didn't change the file in any way (added empty line or such)?

Comment: oh , my bad i had left a empty line now it works fine thank you

Comment: For the empty line problem; you can add a try / except: pass in your for loop. If it can split and extract name and score it would do it, else it will go to the next line.